# Why does the limit in a checkbox not work?

Tags: javascript

I need to limit the number of checkbox checked to three, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function chkcontrol(j) {
   var total=0;
   for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
      if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
         total =total +1;}
      if(total > 3){
         alert("Please Select only three"); 
         document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
         return false; }
   }
}
</script>

    <form name="form1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="0" onclick="chkcontrol(0);">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="1" onclick="chkcontrol(1);">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="2" onclick="chkcontrol(2);">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="3" onclick="chkcontrol(3);">    
    </form>
```

You can test it [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2PTy/4/).

If I use `name="ckb"` instead of `name="ckb[]"`, it does work but I need to use `name="ckb[]"` because in PHP I have this code to extract the values:

```
   foreach($_POST['ckb'] as $value){

   }
```

Comment: I made one solution for you http://jsfiddle.net/nrSh8/ . but It's not good practice to adding inline event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a nicer way to handle this?

```
var form = document.getElementsByName("form1")[0];

form.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     if (event.target.tagName != "INPUT" || event.target.type != "checkbox") {
         return;
     }

     var checked = form.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

     if (checked.length > 3) {
           event.target.checked = false;
     }

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqHBA/).

There are many problems with your JavaScript code and HTML.

- You shouldn't really be using inline event handlers when they're not necessary
- You have 4 checkboxes now, so I handle the event on the form by attaching only one event listener
- You'd probably find it easier to use more modern methods of selecting elements as well

Comment: @alex this is a good solution.. but it will impact any other sets of checkboxes(not of `chkb[]`) on the same page

Comment: @Kshitij It will impact all checkboxes in that `form`, which are all to treated the same (according to the OP's posted HTML).

Comment: @alex OP has just posted part of code. Even if the page does not have extra checkboxes still i consider this as a bad practice as it will impact in the future.

Comment: @alex also, adding `click` event listener for all the elements of the form doesn't sounds good.

Comment: @Kshitij You're making assumptions. The OP is free to modify the selectors to suit if the HTML given differs to their actual application. Your second comment doesn't make any sense (did you read the code?)

Comment: `form.addEventListener("click", function(event) {` doesn't this listen's event of element click inside form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30121/discussion-between-alex-and-kshitij)

Comment: So just to handle 4 check-boxes do you think it good to listen to every element in the form?

Comment: @Kshitij Have a look at how event propagation works. I'm not listening to every element - I'm using the normal propagation to handle the events elsewhere. As, I said, if you want to continue, use the chat link above. Stack Overflow comments should not be full of useless discussion like this.

Comment: unfortunately the chat link is blocked where i work :(. Anyways... to sum up i did find you implementation much neater as i commented very initially..but i will prefer an older approach if it gives better performance and a flexibility in future.

Comment: @Kshitij Better performance? Which metrics did you use to measure and determine that? And can you explain how it's more flexible?

Comment: @alex I already did that in my answers earlier... besides not discussing this any more as this discussion is not going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over form controls named `ckb` but you don't have they. The name of your controls is `ckb[]`.

You need to use `ckb[]` as the property name.

Since `[` and `]` are not allowed in an identifier, you have to use square bracket notation to do so.

`form1['ckb[]']`

Comment: `document.form1.ckb.length` — You didn't fix it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Though the question is already answered i can't stopped myself from posting this alternative solution.

Few important things you need to do  -

1. Pass `this` object as a parameter to your function. This way you
   have a better control without needing to use `chkb[]` inside your
   code.
2. `var total` need to be made global so you don't need to loop everytime.
3. You need to make sure other set of checkboxes(not belonging to `chkb[]`), if any, are not impacted by your code.
4. Change `onclick` to `onchange`. You need your website to respond to keyboard activities also.

See my solution - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2PTy/10/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total=0;
function chkcontrol(chkb) {
   if(chkb.checked){
     if(total >= 3 ){
         chkb.checked=false;    
         alert("Please Select only three");
      } else{
         total=total+1;
      } 
    } else {
        total=total-1;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="form1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="0" onchange="chkcontrol(this);">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="1" onchange="chkcontrol(this);">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="2" onchange="chkcontrol(this);">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="3" onchange="chkcontrol(this);">    
</form>
```

Comment: Your #2 isn't the best advice. For #4, keyboard use still triggers the `click` event.

Comment: @alex #2 is arguable. I agree global variables to not best solution, but looping through 1000's records just to avoid a global variable is definitely not helping you with performance.... regarding #4 as per I remember, older IE versions were not supporting onclick navigation by keyboard. besides `onchange` makes more sense as this is a change event we need to capture.

Comment: When did 4 checkboxes become 1000's of records?